# Style an echoed image

Tags: php, html, css, image

it seems like I cannot style my echoed image in php. How can I do this? Thanks :)

```
<a href="profile.html"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['image'] ).'" height="80px" width="80px" class="img-thumnail" style="margin-bottom:90px;"/></a>
```

Comment: There's no reason why an echo would not work for this. I noticed your class is img-thumnail. Are you perhaps using bootstrap? If so, try class="img-thumbnail" instead

Comment: you have to print it with php tag : <a href="profile.html"><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php base64_encode($row['image'] ); ?>" height="80px" width="80px" class="img-thumnail" style="margin-bottom:90px;"/></a>

Comment: @JNDanial but the code is already inside a php tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This code

```
<img class="im" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'<?php echo base64_encode($row['image'] ); ?>'" height="180px" width="180px" class="img-thumnail" style="margin-bottom:90px;"/>
```